# What is the best website to place orders for electronics components online in the USA?

Tags: components, buying

I need to start ordering electronics components and I am trying to figure out who to use. I want to pick one website to use for all my needs, so they need to have a diverse selection of components, competitive pricing, and relatively quick shipping.

I don't want to shop around to find the lowest cost parts, I just want a reliable company that I can rely on so I don't have to shop around each time I want to go online to order components.

Comment: We're not a shopping advisory site.  Shop around a bit, look at prices on sites you know of, and availability.  Try them out.  You'll soon find your favorites.  You will not find a single site that has everything, only one that has the majority of things, or the best pricing.

Comment: I was hoping to get some opinions and advice from people with proven experience with these kinds of things. Might be helpful for other newbies who come along too.

Comment: There are two Fry's in the ATL area which are OK for basic components you need in a hurry (arguably much better than Radio Shack).  If you find any decent retail shops in the area, particularly the NW corridor, please post back a comment.

Comment: This question can't be answered correctly because the best will depend on many things, such as location, quantity being ordered, etc.

Comment: This could have been closed as off topic for straight purchasing advice, not constructive as there is not a real way for the site to determine a right answer beyond prose and opinions, or as too localized as you have localized to the US.

Comment: I realize this is officially off topic, but I still think this is useful information and that knowing where to get stuff is a important part of designing stuff.  Even if you won't be the one buying the parts, as the designer you should consider availability and price when chosing parts.  My first preference is Mouser as a general supplier.  They have a good web site and seem to have the best prices of any of the major distributors.  Next is DigiKey, also good web site, better stock, but higher prices.

Comment: @weezybizzle - Want more input on this and similar things that don't suit this forums's format? - if so try [here](http://www.piclist.com). Such queries are welcome there.  Both groups are complementary -  belonging to both is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many good companies and you will grow a favorites list with time, but I (in New Zealand) find [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com) very good www.digikey.com.  They have a vast catalog range, much is in stock, prices are usually in the very good to acceptable range. Delivery is rapid and they tend to pick and dispatch same day in almost all cases. Do not be put off by where their HQ is :-).

BUT look at [Findchips](http://www.findchips.com) which will give you some good ideas.

RS are the masters of a vast stock and usually premium prices,

Farnell are a successful RS wannabee.

Look also at Mouser, JameCo, Amazon, ebay !!!, ...

[Findchips](http://www.findchips.com) supplies information for these suppliers:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your geographical location might be relevant, and the general type of components you expect to buy. Personally I like Mouser (minor hassle: filling in the Credit Crad details every time) and Reichelt (but frequently the have no stock for something, then they just delay the order untill they have it all - no partial shipments). I displike DigiKey because (for me, I am in the Netherlands) they want to know what I am going to use certain components for (which I don't want to tell), but they don't tell you up front for which ones!

Answer (score 1):

You generally won't find a single site for everything.

I would agree with the sites others mentioned (Digikey,Mouser, etc.).

Of course, it all depends on what you are looking for... some specialty shops may be more in tune with your specific needs.

In addition, I was surprised at what I could find on Amazon... and how much of it is stocked in-house with free super-saver shipping for orders over $25.  Picked up some Arduinos, soldering equipment, passives (resistors and such), tools, etc. for very good prices.